# Question about Resistor

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Suppose there is a wire in which current is continually increasing at the rate of 10 Amps per second.

What will happen if we suddenly add a resistance in series with that wire?

Will the resistance effect the rate of change of current in that wire?

Or something else will happen?

Please explain this.

Comment: The question makes little sense until we know the circuit which is creating the current rise.

Comment: Echoing what Guy Inchbald said because "current...continually increasing..." is not a natural phenomenon. There is no physical law that says it must happen, nor is there any physical law that says what will happen differently if you insert a resistance into the circuit. If you would describe the complete circuit (i.e., including the part that is _making_ the current increase) then it would be possible for somebody to explain how the addition of a resistor would change its behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a reason for your current to be increasing, so I will assume that you are increasing the voltage continuously. Then, at least naively, $U = RI$ is all you need. When you change the resistance $R$, but "hold" down the voltage $U$ (up to the mentioned continuous increase), the current $I$ has to change. So the rate of change of $I$ will have some discontinuity at the time where you add the resistance and will take on a new value afterwards:
$$ \frac{dI}{dt} = \frac{1}{R}\frac{dU}{dt} - \frac{U}{R^2}\frac{dR}{dt}.$$
So if it were possible to do it instantaneously, your current change would go to minus infinity due to the $\frac{dR}{dt}$ term, which is zero again afterwards, while the rate of change generally changes due to the $R$ factor of the $\frac{dU}{dt}$ term, which (naively, depends on the voltage source) stays constant.

In reality depending on how big the current is at the point of adding the resistance, the high current hitting it instantaneously might melt your resistance, especially if there is some kind of inductance in the circuit resisting a fast change in current.